# Сериализация/Десериализация Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, json, сериализация, словари, десериализация

Есть некий внешний сервис, отдающий такой объект:

```
{
    "timestamp": час
    "asks": масив ордерів на продаж
    [
        [ціна, об'єм]
    ],
    "bids": масив ордерів на покупку
    [
        [ціна, об'єм]
    ]
}
```

Я реализовал его и сериализую с помощью Newtonsoft пакета так:

```
public class Depth
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "timestamp")]
        public int timestamp;

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "asks")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> asks;

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "bids")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> bids;
    }
```

и соответственно место где я получаю данный объект из http запроса и десеарилизую

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var d = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json));
```

В итоге ошибка -->

```
"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array."
```

Возможно для Dictionary имеется какоето другое [сво-во] сериализации или же я неправильно десеарилизую?

Пробовал вмесо Dictionary в классе поля через `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` делать, но тогда значения KeyValuePair равны null.

Comment: Вам же четко написали **масив** - зачем вы пытаетесь массив десериализовать в словарь?

Comment: Почему тогда с листом не работает?

Comment: `Dictionary<string,List<int>>` - Dictionary для занесения имен (asks, bids) в Key, а сам Value у вас обычная коллекция (тут либо list, либо int[], либо что то еще).

Comment: что не работает? Как вы поняли, что не работает? Приведите **пример Json**, **пример кода**, которым вы парсили **и ошибку**, что у вас возникла. Просто фраза "не работает" никому ни о чем не говорит.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ про `timestamp` забыли, он не даст все в словарь собрать.

Comment: @tym32167 Так он же отдельно от словарей. Я как понял json имеет [такой](https://hastebin.com/vehuhifoya.json) вид, тут тогда просто получается класс, который содержит один int и два словаря.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ откуда словари? Там в массивы сущностей с ценой и объемом, судя по `[ціна, об'єм]` из вопроса.

Comment: @ tym32167 я в описании написал, что null - ы в листе приходят.

Comment: Так вы не показали пример json, что парсите. С чего вы взяли, что это `[ціна, об'єм]` вдруг десериализуется в это `KeyValuePair<string,string>`?

Comment: В принципе логика понятна, сделаю лист своих собственных объеков(пар), вот толька каким образом чтоб удобно было с ним потом работать

Comment: tym32167  ` {"timestamp":1530724151,"asks":[["300943.0","0.000299"],["300850.0","0.004703"],["300500.0","0.056"],["300000.0","0.593274"],["299900.0","0.0342"],["299500.0","0.003196"]}`

Comment: массив массивов - както сложновато потом к ним добираться

Comment: так вы можете распарсить как массив массивов, а потом преобразовать в удобную вам форму

Comment: ваш пример json как раз и есть массив массивов double

Comment: tym32167 в любом случае спасибо

Comment: пожалуйста. Как решите проблему, будет полезно запилить ответ

Comment: Сделал List<List<decimal>>, если понадобится другая реализация потом додумаю

Answer (score 2):

Окей, допустим у нас есть json

```
string json = @"{
  ""timestamp"": 1530724151,
  ""asks"": [
    [""300943.0"", ""0.000299""],
    [""300850.0"", ""0.004703""],
    [""300500.0"", ""0.056""],
    [""300000.0"", ""0.593274""],
    [""299900.0"", ""0.0342""],
    [""299500.0"", ""0.003196""]
  ],
  ""bids"": [
    [""300943.0"", ""0.000299""],
    [""300850.0"", ""0.004703""],
    [""300500.0"", ""0.056""],
    [""300000.0"", ""0.593274""],
    [""299900.0"", ""0.0342""],
    [""299500.0"", ""0.003196""]
  ]
}";
```

И мы создали такие классы, которые нам очень нравятся

```
public class Depth
{
    public int timestamp;   
    public MyPair[] asks;   
    public MyPair[] bids;
}

public class MyPair
{
    public decimal Cost{get;set;}
    public decimal Volume{get;set;}
}
```

И теперь мы хотим сконвертировать наш json в наши классы. Но вот незадача - в jsone то поля выглядят как массив массивов, а нам надо массив наших объектов. Что тут можно сделать? А давайте напишем наш конвертер

```
private class MyAwesomeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {       
        return objectType == typeof(MyPair);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray array = JArray.Load(reader);
        return new MyPair 
        { 
            Cost = array[0].Value<decimal>(),
            Volume= array[1].Value<decimal>() 
        };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Этот конвертер будет работать только когда надо будет распарсить конкретно наш класс `MyPair`, для остальных классов будет работать встроенный конвертер. Как теперь все собрать вместе? Вот так:

```
var depth = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Depth>(json, new MyAwesomeConverter());
```

Все, никаких спец объектов больше создавать не нужно.

Comment: +1, но `return objectType == typeof(MyPair);` не совсем точно, вернёт ложь для потомков MyPair же

Comment: @АндрейNOP так нам тут потомки не нужны жеж, я десериализую конкретный тип для конкретного случая

Comment: @tym32167 , а если в вашем джейсоне в некоторых местах цену представить в таком фармате `1.45Е-6`    `[""300943.0"", ""299E-6""],
    [""300850.0"", ""4703E-6""],` ваш вариант сработает?  Сейчас столкнулся с этим, обычный Convert.ToDecimal() выдает ошибку не правильного формата строки.

Comment: @РоманТимохов не спрашивайте меня что будет, если что то сделать. Просто сделайте сами и проверяйте результат. Я вам показал конвертер для конкретного типа. Если у вас с другим типом проблемы - то вы можете написать аналогичный конвертер для другого типа.

Answer (score 1):

Все довольно просто:

```
public class Depth
{
    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public int Timestamp;

    [JsonProperty("asks")]
    public List<Quote> Asks;

    [JsonProperty("bids")]
    public List<Quote> Bids;
}

public class Quote : List<decimal>
{
    public decimal Price => Count > 0 ? this[0] : -1;
    public decimal Volume => Count > 1 ? this[1] : -1;
}
```